# Объединить / склеить многоуровневые названия columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Расчитала таблицу с помощью groupby() и pivot(), в результате получились многоуровневые названия колонок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо получить одноуровневые названия вида **"Позиция 01.10.2021"**.
Какой есть способ это сделать?

Таблица обновляется каждую неделю, поэтому важно, чтобы это делалось с помощью готового метода / функции

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы так должно получиться:

```
df.columns = [f'Позиция {lev2}' for lev1, lev2 in df.columns]
```

Если у вас есть и другие какие-то колонки помимо указанных, то будет несколько сложнее, наверное, но покажите содержимое вашего `df.columns` тогда.